# Calling an array Item from another class

Tags: c#, singleton

I got this bit of code here:

```
IEnemy[] Enemy = new IEnemy[2];
Enemy Goblin = new Enemy("Goblins", "Looks dirty and not so friendly", 100);
Enemy[0] = Goblin;
```

I can use it easily with this: `Goblin.EnemyEncounter();`.

First I like One-Liner when possible, so is it possible to make it smaller?

Second, I created my enemy in the Main, but I always try to keep my main small and tidy, so I want to use another class where i create these enemies and I can call them from my Main or any other class. I was thinking about Singleton, I'm just not so sure if it's the right thing to use or a static array.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a parent class that has a list of other entities.

Something like:

```
var world = new World();
world.Enemies.Add(new Enemy{type="Goblin"});
world.Heros.Add(new Hero{name="Bart Simpson"});
Etc...
```

World would need to have collections defined for each type, such as: Enemies, Heros, Vehicles, Treasure, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!